# Animating Beamer slides with pstricks code in them

Tags: beamer, pstricks, animate

I have made a beamer presentation and have a series of the slides with pstricks images on them. Each of these images either builds upon the previous, or moves an element of the previous. Is there a way I can set up the presentation so I only have to click once to run the whole series of slides?

Note: I have attempted to use the \animate command as described in the Beamer manual, but have had no success.

Comment: Her are a lot of examples: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Animation/basics

Answer (score 1):

A best practice approach (IMHO):

### Step 1

Put each diagram in a separate compilable input file with `standalone` document class as follows.

```
% frames.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \r in {0.1,0.2,...,1.0}{%
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
    \pscircle(2,2){\r}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Because the diagram is already in a single, separate, standalone input file, it will be faster if you compile it with `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf` to obtain a PDF output.

Note: Other alternative approaches to compile the diagram are either

- with `xelatex` (but extremely slow), or
- with `pdflatex -shell-escape` with `auto-pst-pdf` package loaded.

In this example I will use the first approach which is using `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. Do the following in your terminal.

```
latex frames.tex
dvips frames.dvi
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None frames.ps
```

Advantages of separating each diagram into a standalone input file:
 - we can reuse the code for many projects.
 - we can locate the errors if any easily.
 - we can reduce the amount of time needed to compile the code during development phase. Consider the opposite if you put all code in a single main input file; it will waste much of your time if you recompile the main input file  again and again during development phase whenever you just edit some code to see the effect.

### Step 2

Import the frames you already prepared as explained in the first step from within your beamr document as follows. Compile it with `pdflatex` (preferred as you can make use of `microtype` effectively).

```
% main.tex 
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Animation}
    \begin{center}
        \animategraphics[autoplay,scale=1,loop,controls]{3}{frames}{}{}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

From your terminal, invoke the following.

```
pdflatex main.tex
```

And you will get the animation in question. Done

### Simulation

The following simulates everything explained above as a single step.

```
% compile it with 
% pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex

% the filename of this code is main.tex 
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{frames.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \r in {0.1,0.2,...,1.0}{%
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
    \pscircle(2,2){\r}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space frames.\ext}}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Animation}
    \begin{center}
        \animategraphics[autoplay,scale=1,loop,controls]{3}{frames}{}{}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compile it with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex
```

Comment: `animate` also provides `draft` and `final` options that can be used with the `animateinline` environment to reduce compilation time in the all-in-one-file approach.